# Video recording with owners permission

Tags: privacy, recording, sweden

We are currently in the process of creating a service that records video (in this case in a non-profit tennis court) of the people at the location practicing and/or playing. This is not meant for or used in any way for security or surveillance purposes but the videos are meant to be sold back to the person/people playing or training. This would make for much higher quality video than simply having a friend record your game with their smartphone and wouldn't even need a friend to be there.

We have the owners permission to set up cameras.
The question is: how legal is this?

We are in Sweden.

Comment: Do the players know they are being recorded? Can they choose whether or not they get recorded? How long do you store the videos?

Comment: @Philipp They would know they are being recorded. We could have a feature that disables recording of a court or the entire hall on demand. That is entirely configurable but we would prefer to store them for a few days at least.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this article](http://www.loc.gov/law/foreign-news/article/sweden-district-court-declares-drone-use-does-not-constitute-camera-surveillance/), the Malmö Administrative District Court found that the intent of the user is immaterial to whether a camera is being used for surveillance, so even if that is not why you are doing this, it counts legally as "surveillance". The law requires a permit from the länsstyrelse (county? government), according to the [Kameraövervakningslag (2013:460)](http://www.notisum.se/rnp/sls/lag/20130460.htm) (article 8 states the requirement for permit, art. 16 tells you who to apply to). I believe that a tennis court would be considered a "public place", even if privately owned. Art. 17 tells you what goes into an application (there is probably a form), and art. 18 says that the kommun gets to weigh in. Presumably it would be critical to have a consent form signed before any recording happens, and you would include that in the application.